# is there a way to find out the max theoritical score from an elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a search that's purely based on attributes rather than any text searching. I'd like to know if there's a way to interpret the scores returned from elasticsearch in such a way as to determine if a match is good or not (or how good it is on a scale of 0-100)..

The scores obviously change based on the query - if I ask for things that have 5 attributes using an OR search - those that have all 5 get a highscore, whilst those with 1 get a lower score (which is fine..) - I'd like to know if there's an easy way to ask ES: `given this query, what's the max score anything could give me?`

I could do things like say that this result is a 90% match to your query, this one is a 50% match. Rather than this one scored 1.746373..

I'd rather not be double checking each result against the search to work this out..